# In Python how can I assign a set of random values as value pair to a dictionary data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
import random


def sample() -> None:
    file_name = "something" + '.txt'
    with open('C:/Users/xyz/PycharmProjects/some/{0}'.format(file_name), 'w') as f:
        shop_list = [Fruit_shop, Games_shop, Dress_Shop]
        random_shop = random.choice(shop_list)
        for key, value in random_shop.items():
            f.write(key + '\n')
            for key1, value1 in value.items():
                f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
            f.write(f"{'}'}")
            f.write(f"\n\n")

Fruit_shop = {
    'Fruits {':{
        'A':'Apple',
        'B':'Ball'
    }
}
Games_shop = {
    'Games {':{
        'A':'Cricket',
        'B':'Football'
    }
}

Dress_Shop = {
    'Dresses {':{
        'A':'Jeans',
        'B':'Shirts'
    }
}
sample()
```

Expecting an output something like this:-
1st Iteration -

```
Fruits {
A :=Apple
B :=Ball
}
```

2nd iteration -

```
Games{
A :=Jeans
B :=Shirts
}
```

3rd itertation -

```
Dresses{
A :=Cricket
B :=Football
}
```

Whenever the above code is run, with each iteration I want the value of A to be either Apple or Cricket or Jeans, similarly B: Ball or Football or Shirts, I think we need to use the random module here, can any one help me how to do that please? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Could you show a sample of the desired output as properly formatted text in the question?

Comment: Do not build JSON yourself (additionally makes your code easier to read/maintain), there is [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: Hey, I have updated the question with desired output as properly formatted text

Comment: So, just to clarify, for one iteration, you want to pick a random shop that could be either `Fruit`, `Games` or `Dresses` and then for that shop pick item `A` from either `Apple`, `Cricket` or `Jeans`, and item `B` from either `Ball`, `Football` or `Shirts`? Or, do the pairs of items, `A` and `B` always have to be together, i.e., Cricket and Football always have to be together, but in a random shop?

Comment: Hey @MattPitkin I dont want them in pairs, I want them in random, even if we can create a list (something like `product_A =["Apple", "Jeans", "Cricket"]`) and with each iteration I want the dictionary to iterate over that list and assign either of the 3 values from that list as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should do what you are after:

```py
import random

shops = ["Fruit", "Games", "Dresses"]
productA = ["Apple", "Jeans", "Cricket"]
productB = ["Ball", "Shirts", "Football"]

def sample(shops, productA, productB, outputfile="something.txt"):
    with open(outputfile, "w") as fp:
        shop = random.choice(shops)  # pick random shop
        prodA = random.choice(productA)  # pick random product A
        prodB = random.choice(productB)  # pick random product B

        shopdict = {"A": prodA, "B": prodB}
        fp.write(shop)
        fp.write("{\n")
        for key, value in shopdict.items():
            fp.write(f"{key} :={value}\n")
        fp.write("}\n")

sample(shops, productA, productB)
```